# How is it known that Callisto has no core?

Tags: callisto, core

My Astronomy book claims that scientists have discovered that Callisto, a moon of Jupiter, has no hot inner core. In fact, it says, Callisto has a core much like the nucleus of a comet.

Is this still accepted theory, and how was this information discovered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *may* have a (silicate) core, but it's very small. There also is the possibility of [an internal liquid water "ocean"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103505001806). Currently the most probable composition is that of rock and ice, [with the density of rock steadily increasing as one digs deeper](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/280/5369/1573) (This is in stark contrast with planets like Earth, where there are discontinuities in the density between layers). [Planetary differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_differentiation) has not occurred appreciably because Callisto is not [tidally heated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration#Tidal_heating).

The composition can never be completely determined — the composition of a spherical body cannot be fully discerned from just rotation and translation<sup>1</sup>. However, we can make reasonable guesses. Basically, we can calculate its total mass and moment of inertia by observing its rotation and revolution. Then, assuming that the density ρ varies radially, we get the following two equations:

$$M = \int \rho \pi r^2dr$$

$$I = \int (\rho \pi r^2dr)r^2$$

These do not completely determine ρ, however with other reasonable assumptions on the composition and the amount of planetary differentiation it can have, we can get a good estimate for ρ.

<sup>1. It *can* be determined if we take a larger gravitational field and pivot it, but this ventures into the Aristotlean "Give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth." zone of thought experiments.</sup>